# Installing a theme - Mint 17.2

Tags: linux-mint, theme

I've just done a fresh install of Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon and would like to install a theme but haven't had any luck. (I've never installed a theme before).

I have downloaded the sable theme from www.noobslab.com/2014/09/another-two-great-dark-themes-sable.html
I followed the installation instructions as explained:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sable-gtk
```

But I am not sure what to do next. This theme is apparently compatible with Cinnamon.

If I go to the Menu->Appearance menu, the theme does not appear. If I click "install" and browse to the `/usr/share/themes` folder, the new them is there, but there is nothing to install. The folder just contains various files so I don't know how to actually activate the theme.

To be clear: I am just using this theme as an example, but have not been able to install any themes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Cinnamon Desktop to try it out but the usual procedure is to go to the Desktop and right mouse click and select "Change Desktop Background".

Then a dialog will open up for changing desktop background. In this dialog, there will be a tab for "Theme". Change to this tab and apply the new theme.

Comment: Thanks. The only thing i've been able to do is to install themes using the method you describe, but when doing that the only thing that changes is the menu bar and menu. None of the windows borders or icons change. Judging by the screenshots of most of the themes, the window borders and icons etc should change as well, not just the main menu?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also running Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon using a theme from `ppa:noobslab/themes` and I found that after installing the theme, the way you describe, the theme shows up in *System Settings* `->` *Themes* in the *Window borders* and *Controls* lists (though no preview is available). When selected, I need to relog for the changes to work properly, but I don't need to manually install anything.

Btw, I'm using the "mediterranean-theme".

Answer (score -1):

I installed Mint 17.2 Cinnamon and was horrified that I was not able to customize window appearances & behaviors (themes, colors, and especially keyboard shortcuts--the keyboard shortcuts app in Cinnamon was both uglier than the one I was used to and also just wouldn't accept any shortcuts I typed in). Then I installed 17.2 **Mate** and could customize to my heart's content. I don't know why they don't let you customize in Cinnamon, but they just don't. Mint Mate may be more what you're looking for.